# How to close popup layout on outside click?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working in xamarin forms. I am usng PopupLayout control to show the popup on screen. Now I want that if user click outside the popup popup should be dismiss. How I can do this? What property of PopupLayout I can use?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have a transparent `ContentView` covering the screen. Add a `GestureRecognizer` to the `ContentView` which, when clicked, will hide the `PopupControl`.

When the `PopupControl` is not showing, set `ContentView.InputTransparent` to `true` so clicks do not register, or remove the `ContentView` from the screen completely.

When you show the `PopupControl`, set `ContentView.InputTransparent` to `false` or add in the `ContentView` if you removed it.